# In Spring MVC, how to gracefully handle Validate.notNull IllegalArgumentException when a "get by id" finds no item?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, error-handling

I have a Spring MVC web app and use Hibernate for persistence.

I have a table of vehicles.  Each vehicle has a unique ID.

One webpage in my app lists all of the vehicles (www.example.com/vehicles).  Clicking on a link takes you to the details page of that vehicle via a GET parameter of the vehicle's ID (www.example.com/vehicles?id=1234).

This is all fine because if a vehicle gets deleted from the table, that vehicle no longer appears on the page that lists all vehicles, so there is no link to click.

**However, if someone supplies an id of a vehicle that does not exist (e.g. they had bookmarked the path of a particular vehicle but that vehicle has since been deleted--e.g. www.example.com/vehicles?id=1234) and that vehicle is no longer in the database, there is an exception.**

```
Vehicle vehicle = vehicleDAO.findById(id);
Validate.notNull(vehicle, "There is no vehicle by this ID.");
```

**My controller will reach these couple lines and will throw an IllegalArgumentException on the line with Validate.notNull.
How can I code a site-wide handler for gracefully telling a website visitor the message that appears in that Validate.notNull statement?**

I think Validate.notNull statements are useful throughout my code, and I'd like to send their messages all the way to the browser window so that the visitor doesn't just see some generic 500 Error page.

This applies not just to my Vehicles table but to anything.

It would be nice to have just one bit of code that gracefully handles this problem for all controllers throughout the site.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should do it that way.  What you would be doing is handling all IllegalArgumentExceptions that propagate out of the controller on the assumption that they all can / should be reported to the end user.  That's not sound practice because Spring (and other libraries) use that exception for all sorts of things.

You need to treat this is a special case.  Write a special validator to test for the deleted vehicle case, and have it throw a **custom** exception.  Then either handle that explicitly in the controller or more generically.

Comment: Right, I don't mean to do that.  But I'm wondering if I could write something to use instead of Validate.notNull that can be used on any object and can bounce the user to an error page with a message. It would be void CheckForNull(Object object, String errorMessage) and if object was null, print the supplied error message on a certain view. Thoughts? How could I do this?

Comment: You could do it, but I think it would not help.  The problem is that each context needs to be handled differently.  Sometimes you want to treat the null as not an error and just do something different.  Sometimes you want to report it as a "bad input" error.  Sometimes you want to treat it as a "the data is unavailable" error.  Sometimes you want to treat it as "there's a bug in the application".  Trying to handle all of these with a single mechanism is (IMO) not going to work.

Comment: Of course I'd only use it where the desired behavior would be bouncing the user to an error page with that supplied message (saying "You were looking for item [item type] of ID [x], but it doesn't exist").  Sort of like a 404 error page.  In other cases I'd call different methods to handle the nulls differently.

Answer (score 0):

you should check id correctness in service layer. if id incorrect, throw custom exception and handle it